# HP 430 AND 630 graphics drivers

Tags: drivers, hp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

My HP 630 laptop is Rrunning in low graphics mode. What can I do?

Comment: What is your graphics configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Open jocky-gtk(default installed). It will show you additional driver which need to install. Select appropriate driver and hit on active button. What is your graphics configuration ?